# How to check a ckeck box on condition in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to show my check box as check depending on `student.ispresent` but its not working i.e not getting `checked` with `ng-checked`.

```
<div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat = 'student in vm.students'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-6">
            {{student.name}}{{student.ispresent}}
        </label>
        <div class="btn-group col-sm-6" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-white" ng-click="vm.checkValues(student.id,'Yes')">
                <input type="radio" name="" value="" autocomplete="off" ng-checked="student.ispresent ==='Yes' "> Yes
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-white" ng-click="vm.checkValues(student.id,'No')">
                <input type="radio" name="" value="" autocomplete="off" ng-checked="student.ispresent ==='Yes' "> No
             </label>
        </div><!--btn-group col-sm-6-->
    </div><!--form_group-->
</div><!--//col-sm-6-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed to set `ng-model` in your checkbox control

```
<label class="btn btn-white" ng-click="vm.checkValues(student.id,'Yes')">
   <input type="radio" name="" value="" autocomplete="off" ng-model="StudentYes" ng-checked="student.ispresent ==='Yes' "> Yes
</label>
<label class="btn btn-white" ng-click="vm.checkValues(student.id,'No')">
   <input type="radio" ng-model="StudentNo" name="" value="" autocomplete="off" ng-checked="student.ispresent ==='Yes' "> No
</label>
```

and kindly call the `ng-click event` in the `check box` instead of `label`

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) directives along with `ngTrueValue` and `ngFalseValue` see [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

```
<input type="checkbox" 
     ng-model="student.ispresent" 
     ng-true-value="Yes" 
     ng-false-value="No" />
```

Note: There seems to be no need for `ng-click`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/9dy8cvvq/2/)